# How to get FormatConditions.Formula1 in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I need to check using VBA if a user has applied a certain Conditional Formatting to a specific range in a worksheet.

I can use this:

```
If Worksheets(1).Range("B2:B10").FormatConditions(1).Formula1 = the_formula Then
    ' some code
End If
```

For that I need to get *the_formula*. I applied conditional formatting to the range and used this:

```
Debug.Print Worksheets(1).Range("B2:B10").FormatConditions(1).Formula1
```

This gives me an error. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please, share `the_formula`. It may not be correct. I mean, the string formula does not look exactly like the one written in a sheet formula. Some double quotes have to  be doubled, for instance...

Comment: Check these for me please **1.** What happens when you change `Worksheets(1)` with say `Worksheets("Relevantsheet name")` or with it's code name. **2.** Manually check if the range actually has aCF formula

Comment: "This give me an error" witch error?

Comment: Is it likely that the `Formula1` is the same for all cells in the range?

Comment: Your code works for me. If the format set is different in the cells it returns the format set for the last cell in the range that has any format set. It returns an error 13 (subscript) if no format is set in any of the cells.

Comment: @FaneDuru I used 'Format only values that are above or below average'. I don't know what the corresponding the_formula will be.

Comment: @VincentG 'Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method'

Comment: If you do not know "what the corresponding the_formula will be", why do you try `Worksheets(1).Range("B2:B10").FormatConditions(1).Formula1 = the_formula`? If all the range has the same (initial) formula, the range formula will return the first cell of the range formula. Which is incremented in the next cells, but this does not matter in your case... Anyhow, can you show us one of these formulas?

Comment: @FaneDuru I am using 'Format only values that are above or below average' to highlight the above-average values in a range. I want to make sure other users also use the same conditional formatting. For that, I need to get the Formula1 of the range in which I have applied CF, using `Debug.Print Worksheets(1).Range("B2:B10").FormatConditions(1).Formula1` , and then I can use the particular formula in place of *the_formula*. *the_formula* is not a variable name, I just used that name because I don't know that the formula is.

Comment: If **you do not use a formula"", there is nothing to be returned using `Debug.Print Worksheets(1).Range("B2:B10").FormatConditions(1).Formula1`. It will return an error.

Comment: I am not sure why did you ignore my comment. If you would have checked what I mentioned in point 2 in my comment above, you would not have wasted 1 hour approx :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I am an absolute beginner in Excel and VBA, and was under the impression that every CF has a corresponding formula. That's what caused the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your range `Formatconditions` does not involve a formula and uses  'Format only values that are above or below average (above)', try the next way, please:

```
If Worksheets(1).Range("B2:B10").FormatConditions(1).AboveBelow = xlAboveAverage Then
    ' some code...
End If
```